# Does any embedded DB support JSON datatype?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm developing a Spring based web application with postgresql as database. I'm using JSON Datatype in postgresql. I have configured the entity with hibernate custom user type to support JSON Datatype.

Now i want to test my DAO objects using any embedded DB. Is there any embedded DB that support JSON data type which can be used in spring application.

Comment: Using a different DBMS for testing than in production is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Databases like H2, HSQLDB or any other inmemory db support JSON type?

Comment: I am trying actually to get around it by stubbing this type with a custom script: `DROP TYPE json IF EXISTS; CREATE TYPE json AS text;` for HSQLDB. It does not solve any problems but at least the schema is created. The problem I am getting now is an exception by inserting a row.

Comment: H2 does by now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620317/how-can-solve-json-column-in-h2/50837767

Answer (score 6):

When you use database specific features - like *JSON* support in *PostgreSQL*, for safety you have to use the same type of database for testing. In your case you want to test your *DAO* objects:

- assume that *PostgreSQL* is installed on localhost and make sure that it is the case for all environments where tests run
- or even better - try using [otj-pg-embedded](https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded) which downloads and starts *PostgreSQL* for *JUnit* tests (I haven't used it in real life projects)

**Update**

If you are able to run Docker in your test environment instead of embedded databases use real Postgres via [TestContainers](http://testcontainers.org)

Comment: I could use Postgres but as part of unit testing I should use in memory database like H2. In H2 there is PosgreSQL compatibility mode but it doesn't have JSON type. So i assume, the only option is to use POSTRGRES itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
            package miniCodePrjPkg;

            import java.util.List;
            import java.util.Map;

            import org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner;
            import org.apache.commons.dbutils.handlers.MapListHandler;

            import java.sql.Connection;
            import java.sql.DriverManager;
            import java.sql.SQLException;
            import java.sql.Statement;

            import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
            import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
            import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
            import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
            import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
            import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

            //import com.wix.mysql.EmbeddedMysql;
            //
            //import static com.wix.mysql.EmbeddedMysql.anEmbeddedMysql;
            //import static com.wix.mysql.ScriptResolver.classPathScript;
            //import static com.wix.mysql.distribution.Version.v5_7_latest;

            public class DslQueryCollList {
                public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                    // apache comm coll cant ,only array is ok..cant json_object eff
                    // Map m=Maps.
                    Map myMap = Maps.newHashMap(ImmutableMap.of("name", 999999999, "age", 22));
                    Map myMap2 = Maps.newHashMap(ImmutableMap.of("name", 8888888, "age", 33));

                    List li = new ImmutableList.Builder().add(myMap).add(myMap2).build();
                    System.out.println(li);
                    // /db/xx.sql
            //   EmbeddedMysql mysqld = anEmbeddedMysql(v5_7_latest)
            //              .addSchema("aschema", classPathScript("iniListCache.sql"))
            //              .start();

                    // this just start..and u need a cliednt as common to conn..looks trouble than
                    // sqlite
                    String sql = " json_extract(jsonfld,'$.age')>30";

                    List<Map<String, Object>> query = queryList(sql, li);
                    System.out.println(query);
                    // run.query(conn, sql, rsh)
                }

                private static List<Map<String, Object>> queryList(String sql_query, List li)
                
                        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, JsonProcessingException {
                sql_query="SELECT * FROM sys_data where "+sql_query;
                
                    String sql = null;
                    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

                    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
                    Statement stmt = c.createStatement();

                    String sql2 = "drop TABLE sys_data ";
                    exeUpdateSafe(stmt, sql2);
                    sql2 = "CREATE TABLE sys_data (jsonfld json  )";
                    exeUpdateSafe(stmt, sql2);

                    // insert into facts values(json_object("mascot", "Our mascot is a dolphin name
                    // sakila"));
                    //
                    for (Object object : li) {
                        String jsonstr = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(object);
                        sql = "insert into sys_data values('" + jsonstr + "');";
                        // sql = "insert into sys_data values('{\"id\":\"19\", \"name\":\"Lida\"}');";
                        exeUpdateSafe(stmt, sql);

                    }

                    //sql = "SELECT json_extract(jsonfld,'$.name') as name1 FROM sys_data limit 1;";
                //  System.out.println(sql);
                    QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner();
                    // maphandler scare_handler
                    System.out.println(sql_query);
                    List<Map<String, Object>> query = run.query(c, sql_query, new MapListHandler());
                    System.out.println(query);
                    List li9=Lists.newArrayList();
                    for (Map<String, Object> map : query) {
                        li9.add(map.get("jsonfld"));
                    }
                    return li9;
                }

                private static void exeUpdateSafe(Statement stmt, String sql2) throws SQLException {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(sql2);
                        System.out.println(stmt.executeUpdate(sql2));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!