# JSON data column in liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I want to create a table with a column called data which will store json data.How do i add that column in my xml file and also how do i make it in my Model class.Currently i am going like this but i have no idea if it is correct.

```
 <changeSet author="ABC" id="HUI">
        <createTable tableName="archived_table">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"
                             primaryKeyName="archive_tablePK" />
            </column>
            <column name="created" type="TIMESTAMP(6)">
            </column>
            <column name="data" type="jsonb"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

As for my Model class i am going like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "archived_table")
public class ArchiveModel extends  BaseModel{
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private JSONObject data;

public ArchiveDataModel(
            JSONObject data,
    ){
        super();
        this.data=data;
    }

 public JSONObject getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(JSONObject data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not keen on the idea of databases having field types specific to a format, but a json data type does exist in Postgres.  Here is another question with several answers.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49834222/5611377

Answer (score 2):

The type of your column should be `String` and you should write the value using `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString()`, and read it using `ObjectMapper.readValue`. Then it should be clear how to handle it with liquibase.

Comment: what i want is to create a table which will have a column of json data type.I am not going to use that table for any data fetching.I just simply want a table with json Data type column in which i can manually enter json data by sql query.

Comment: I agree in principal.  Store it as a string and let a higher level of code deal with JSON encoding/decoding.  But... some databases now have a "JSON" type.  See above comment for a link to people who have answers.