# JSON datatype with Spring boot with hibernate in test environment

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, junit, in-memory-database

I am developing a project using Spring boot & Hibernate . I am using MySQL database in this application.
In this application, some columns are of JSON type.
I have also written Junit test case with MySQL database for this application.

Now I wants to use any in-memory database for Junit test case. I have tried  H2, HSQL & Debry for this.
I am failing to configure this database because these in-memory databases do not support the JSON data type.
If I use MySQL database for Junit test case then it is works fine, but as soon as I change the database to an in-memory database then it fails to work.

Is there any solution for this JSON datatype ?

> Note: It is necessary to use JSON column type in application so I can't change this JSON column type.

Comment: JSON is basically just a string/varchar. I guess there is a way to use this as solution

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion XtremeBaumer But I as of now JSON is necessary to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can solve JSON column in H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620317/how-can-solve-json-column-in-h2)

Comment: They are suggesting to use CLOB data type instead of JSON. But as I said earlier that JSON type is necessary to use for column.

Comment: Read the more upvoted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837767/7109162